# var let is ok but let let isn't?

Tags: javascript

```js
//Version A:
var let = true;
console.log(let);//true
```

```js
//Version B:
let let = 0; //syntax Error: let is disallowed as a lexically bound name
console.log(let);
```

Is there any particular reason where we allow variable with name `let` created using `var` but not `let`? With this experiment, is that also means that variable name `let` is ok to exist on global level but not in some scope level? But isn't global is consider scope?

Comment: It looks like you can also `var let = true;` inside a function, not necessarily on the global level

Comment: I guess this is lexer and parser issue. parser will grammatically mark let in var let as a variable declaration..

Comment: Don't see how this would be helpful in any situation.

Comment: to avoid breaking old code from before `let` was introduced ..

Comment: `let` declarations are a recent addition to the language, so in order to avoid breaking an unknown fraction of the internet the language allows `let` to be used as an identifier.

Comment: but wasn't `const` added at the same time? Why doesn't this behavior transfer to `const`?

Comment: @Pointy I have to assume that if they felt enough to have `let` be backwards compatible like  that, they would have done the same with `const`?

Comment: @cquezel Most likely so, but I'm not hip on history haha. That still begs the question of why let is restricted (or should I say disallowed, `let let` or `const let` error out saying 'let' is disallowed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the specification says so.

From https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations-static-semantics-early-errors:

> ### 13.3.1 Let and Const Declarations
>
> #### 13.3.1.1 Static Semantics: Early Errors
>
> *LexicalDeclaration* `:` *LetOrConst* *BindingList* `;`
>
> - It is a Syntax Error if the BoundNames of *BindingList* contains **`"let"`**.

The [variable statement specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-variable-statement) has no such limitation, probably because `let` was not in use at the time `var` was defined, and changing the specification for `var` would be a breaking change.

Answer (score 7):

It's due to backwards compatibility, as you guessed. `const` [has always been a reserved word](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-7.6.1.2) (called a `FutureReservedWord` in the ES5 spec). You've never been able to name a variable `const`, since the beginning of JavaScript.

`let` had also been considered to be a `FutureReservedWord`, but *only in strict mode* - but strict mode was only introduced with ES5, when ES6 was on the distant horizon.

```js
'use strict';
let = 10; // errors
```

`var` has always existed, so naming a variable `var` has always been forbidden.

Variables have never been able to be named `const`, but there was no such restriction with `let`. If it had been made forbidden in (non-strict) ES5 or ES6, it would have broken backwards compatibility, which web standards [strive not to break at all costs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55934490/why-are-await-and-async-valid-variable-names).

If, back when JS was first engineered, people had the foresight to think: "Maybe, in the future, we'll want to use the words `const` and `let` to declare variables, so we'll make them reserved keywords for now." Then you wouldn't see the inconsistency, because both would have been reserved from the beginning.

There are a number of similar keywords that sometimes have a special meaning in modern JS, but don't throw errors when used as variable names.

```js
static = 5;
async = 10;
await = 15;
yield = 20;
console.log('finished without errors');
```

Comment: `await = 10` throws in an `async` function and `yield = 20` throws in a "generator" function

Comment: Yep, which is permitted because those functions introduce their own cover grammars without breaking backwards compatibility

Comment: I was just pointing out that the list isn't *always* correct, i.e. in async or generator function - also, `await = 10` probably won't work where top-level-await is allowed

Answer (score 4):

`const` and `let` are recent additions to JS, but for a *long* time before they were added `const` was a reserved keyword (presumably on the basis that it was thought to be a likely future addition to the language).

Since `let` used to be a valid variable name, this is presumably for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Using `let` as a variable name is *really confusing* since it is a language keyword. Supporting it with `var` allows for compatibility with existing code that predates `let` as a keyword. That reason doesn't apply to new code and code using `let` or `const` must be new code

Answer (score 4):

`const` and `let` have been introduced as *Future Reserved Words* in [ECMA2011](https://www.ecma-international.org/archive/ecmascript/2010/TC39/tc39-2010-062-Rev6.pdf).

### ECMA2011 - Introduction of `const` and `let` as Future Reserved Words

> **7.6.1.2 Future Reserved Words**
>
> The following words are used as keywords in proposed extensions and
> are therefore reserved to allow for the possibility of future adoption
> of those extensions.
>
> *FutureReservedWord ::*
>
> - **class**
> - **enum**
> - **extends**
> - **super**
> - **const**
> - **export**
> - **import**
>
> The following tokens are also considered to be *FutureReservedWords*
> when they occur within strict mode code (see 10.1.1). The occurrence
> of any of these tokens within strict mode code in any context where
> the occurrence of a *FutureReservedWord* would produce an error must
> also produce an equivalent error:
>
> - **implements**
> - **let**
> - **private**
> - **public**
> - **yield**
> - **interface**
> - **package**
> - **protected**
> - **static**

### ECMA2012 - Approved keywords

Later on in [ECMA2012](https://www.ecma-international.org/archive/ecmascript/2012/TC39/tc39-2012-088.pdf) both words were added as keywords, which may not be used as *identifiers*.

> **7.6.1.1 Keywords**
>
> The following tokens are ECMAScript keywords and may not be used as
> *Identifiers* in ECMAScript programs.
>
> *Keyword ::*
>
> - **break**
> - **delete**
> - **import**
> - **this**
> - **case**
> - **do**
> - **in**
> - **throw**
> - **catch**
> - **else**
> - **instanceof**
> - **try**
> - **class**
> - **export**
> - **let**
> - **typeof**
> - **continue**
> - **finally**
> - **new**
> - **var**
> - **const**
> - **for**
> - **return**
> - **void**
> - **debugger**
> - **function**
> - **super**
> - **while**
> - **default**
> - **if**
> - **switch**
> - **with**

Whereas `const` used as *identifier* is throwing errors in every mode, `let` only throws an error while being in strict mode, which is still the case nowadays using your example:

### Valid

**Using `let` as identifier without strict mode.**

```js
(function(){
    //REM: Works
    var let = 5;
    console.log(let);
  })();
```

### Invalid

**Using `const` as identifier without strict mode.**

```js
(function(){
    //REM: Throws an error
    var const = 5;
    console.log(const);
})();
```

**Using either `let` or `const` as identifiers in strict mode.**

```js
(function(){
    'use strict';
    //REM: Throws an error
    var let = 5;
    console.log(let);
})();
```

```js
(function(){
    'use strict';
    //REM: Throws an error
    var const = 5;
    console.log(const);
})();
```

So historically ECMA was more strict with the keyword `const` than `let` from the get go. While `let` may not be used as *Identifier* since ECMA2012, I assume it was overlooked due to backwards compatibility.

[Here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-let-and-const-declarations) is the latest specification of `let` and `const`.

Comment: Much appreciated. And marked accepted for completeness.And this makes sense, the REPL isn't in 'strict mode' so it didn't complain about the minor violations

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any particular reason where we allow variable with name let created using var but not let?

It's allowed in `var` for backwards compatibility.

`let` declarations didn't exist prior to the ES2015 standard, so `let` could be used freely as a variable name. Changing the language to stop allowing that variable name could have broken applications which were written before ES2015 existed, at a time when `let` was a perfectly good variable name. (Which covered a period of twenty years -- 1995 to 2015!)

Since `let` was a new feature, there was no existing code to break, and disallowing `let` as a variable name avoided a potential source of syntactic confusion.