# Is there a case where using bind would not cover the need for using either call or apply?

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript via [javascript.info](https://javascript.info).
I learned about `bind` (and a lesson before about `call` and `apply`)
I see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15455009/1219280) inquires about the differences on all 3.

After reading all that, I wonder: is there a scenario where using `bind` would NOT cover the need for using either `call` or `apply` ?
I mean, `call` or `apply` are meant for calling the function immediately. `bind` - later on.

Would not the following work in all cases?

```
let f = function(){/* code here */};
let errorFreeF = f.bind(myContextObj);
errorFreeF();
```

A less verbose snippet:

```
function(){/* code here */}.bind(myContextObj)();
```

If the answer is using bind is always safe and indeed covers all scenarios, seems like the call/apply could be deprecated in future JS versions ? Or it performs worse?

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use `.bind` as a substitute for `.call` and `.apply`. If you wanted, you could convert all uses of `.call` and `.apply` with `.bind`.

The other combinations are true as well. If you really wanted to, you could also replace all instances of those methods with `.call`, or with `.apply`.

It's just that it's sometimes inelegant to do so. For similar reasons, even though `Array.prototype.forEach` could be used to identify an element which matches a condition in an array, `Array.prototype.find` is more appropriate and requires less code.

> seems like the call/apply could be deprecated in future JS versions ?

No, for a few reasons:

- They're useful methods to have (they can result in cleaner code than having to write the same thing with `.bind`)
- Using `.bind` creates a function. In rare cases, the extra overhead resulting from the creation of a function may be a problem. (But `.call` and `.apply` only *invoke* functions, they don't *create* functions)
- The language designers will never implement a change (such as removing `.call` or `.apply`) because that will break existing websites, which is [avoided at all costs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55934491).

Comment: Not just less code, but my gut feeling also says using `call` and `apply` would have much better performance in a tight loop etc than repeatedly re-binding to different contexts

Comment: Yeah, probably, Though, performance is almost never a concern in 99% of code blocks one is writing/analyzing.

Comment: Yeah - though I've just spent all morning with my head in performance sensitive code, so that's where it's at at the moment I guess!

Comment: Should not your "No" be "Yes" :) (I ask if using calling the binded function on the spot would not always do the job - seems you say yes, it would). Regarding more elegant/less verbose code, of course my sample should be `function(){}.bind(myContext)()`; Using bind would still be more verbose but the underlying question is: if bind is enough for every scenario, why not deprecate the other ones ? Maybe its performance is worse then the others...