# Why is let not recognised as a keyword in type conversion to string in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, string-interpolation, let, template-literals

Type conversion to string in javaScript apparently ignores let as a keyword.

`String(let)` throws the error *ReferenceError: let is not defined*

Whereas, `String(var)` throws the error *SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'var'*

Is that the intended behaviour?

Comment: What's funnier, is you can do `window['let'] = "foo"` and then `String(let)` returns "foo"...

Comment: Also... `String()` is not "String interpolation", you're describing toString() ("String interpolation" == template literals)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Reserved keywords" cannot be used as identifiers (variable names). `var` [is a reserved keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar).

`let` is not a reserved keyword, because that would break backwards compatibility: ancient scripts written without ES6 in mind that happened to use `let` as a variable name would fail (and browsers try [very hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55934490/why-are-await-and-async-valid-variable-names) not to break backwards compatibility

- see that question for an extended explanation).

So using `String(var)` throws a **syntax** error, but syntactically permits the use of `let` - up until the point where you try to reference it (at which point an error is thrown because no such variable named `let` exists).

For the exact same reason, it's possible to define a variable named `let`, but not to define a variable named `var`:

```js
var let = 123;
console.log(String(let));
```

```js
var var = 123;
console.log(String(var));
```

Also, `let` can't be declared as an identifier in strict mode:

```js
'use strict';
var let = 123;
console.log(String(let));
```

This is possible because if strict mode is being used, the code that is running is guaranteed to have been written after ES5 (and so there isn't any backwards compatibility to worry about).

As a comment notes, this is [not string interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66961382/why-is-let-not-recognised-as-a-keyword-in-type-conversion-to-string-in-javascrip/#comment118362833_66961382). This is just the parser identifying valid variable/identifier names.

Comment: Great answer. You messed up the link to my comment however

Comment: It's interesting the error that `var var` provides...