# Get first 5 key value from object

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have an object with 10 key values,

```
const detail = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5,'f':6,'g':7,'h':8,'i':9,'j':10}
```

I only want to get first 5 key values from object,

```
**{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5}**
```

Like we can slice in array and get first 5 elements, is it possible to do something for the same.

I tried looking for solution, but was unable to find anything related to it.

Any help would really be helpful. If anyone needs any moew details please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get an array of the object's entries (key-value pairs in the form of an array), then slice that array and turn it back into an object:

```js
const detail = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5,'f':6,'g':7,'h':8,'i':9,'j':10};

const sliced = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(detail).slice(0, 5)
);
console.log(sliced);
```

Comment: It does work, however, it should be mentioned, that [`Object.entries` has a defined order only since ES2020, and even since it relies on the insertion order only in case of non-index properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order), that might cause problems.

Comment: @FZs The specification [prefers backwards compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55934491) above all else. The reason it was deemed safe to add this to the specification is because every implementation in use had, at the time, and for many years previously, already had been using that behavior. So I think it's safe to use.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I agree, that's why I wrote "it does work", just wanted to mention it, as relying on unspecified things might yield unexpected results, so it might cause problems. In that case, I think, it's better to know such things beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use `Object.fromEntires` with `Object.entries`

`Object.entries` will return a nested array of key, value pairs, which you can `slice` and then pass that slice to `Object.fromEntries` which will return an object.

```js
const detail = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6, g: 7, h: 8, i: 9, j: 10 };

const res = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(detail).slice(0, 5));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: It does work, however, it should be mentioned, that [`Object.entries` has a defined order only since ES2020, and even since it relies on the insertion order only in case of non-index properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order), that might cause problems.