# Why let and const keyword variables are not allowed to redeclaration in JavaScript, where var keyword variable is allowed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables

I know that variable redeclaration leads us to syntax error and it is illegal but JavaScript has it's own weird concept about redeclaration. please I need guidance about this stuff.

1).I am trying to understand this when we use **var variable in JavaScript it can be redeclared**.
2).The last assigned value will get updated to var identifier.
3).I went through some resources, i got that **v8engine is not redeclaring var it is just assigning the latest value to same var identifier**, ok up to know this is perfect.
4).If it so why the same flexibility of **redeclaring not given to let and const keyword**s in JavaScript.
5).What is happening behind this complex stuff please explain me

Comment: The flexibility is simply deemed not useful.

Comment: Re-declaring a `var` variable is, at best, sloppy and at worst a bug.  `let` and `const` aimed to prevent that sloppiness or accidental bugs by preventing the re-declaration.  Also, by definition, `const` is `const`.  It can't get a new value assigned to it ever so re-declaration for `const` would never ever be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to re-declare a variable of the same name in the same scope is *confusing* to someone reading a script who's trying to understand it. If you declare a variable at a certain line in the code, and then later declare it again, it's very likely a typo or accident, since it doesn't make sense - if you want to reassign the variable, *just reassign the variable* without re-declaring it.

```js
function getName(name) {
  // What did the script-writer mean to do here?
  // Did they forget that there's an argument called name already?
  var name = prompt('What is your name?');
  console.log('hi', name);
}
getName();
```

Re-declaring in the same scope is technically permitted with `var`, but that's only because that's how things have always worked since the very beginning; changing it to be illegal now would break backwards compatibility, which is [not done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55934490/why-are-await-and-async-valid-variable-names).

`let` and `const` were intentionally designed *to not be re-declarable* in order to avoid this sort of confusion. Less confusing code is arguably more important than flexibility. When language rules are *too* flexible, coding can become a lot harder. (see `==` for an example...)

Even if it were possible, re-declaring a `const` variable in particular doesn't make any sense, because a `const` is, by definition, not reassignable.

Comment: thank you so much, i got the point that from let and const they made it strict, am i right?

Comment: Yes, it's usually easier when code is a bit more strict. Though in this case, it's less "more strict" and more "less sloppy".

Comment: Some languages allow redeclaring constants as long as all declarations have the same value :-)