# SyntaxError: Unexpected token "new" when using await new Promise in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code (snippet out of a larger program and within an async function):

```js
foo = questionData.media ? (await new Promise(resolve => {
  const image = new Image();
  image.onload = function () {
    const canvas = document.ceateElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = this.width;
    canvas.height = this.height;
                    
    canvas.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
                    
    resolve(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg"));
  };
                
  image.src = "https://example.com/" + questionData.media;
})) : false;
```

I keep getting `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'new'` on the first line, and I have no idea why. When I try to use parenthesis:

```js
foo = questionData.media ? (await (new Promise(resolve => {
  const image = new Image();
  image.onload = function () {
    const canvas = document.ceateElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = this.width;
    canvas.height = this.height;
                    
    canvas.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
                    
    resolve(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg"));
  };
                
  image.src = "https://example.com/" + questionData.media;
}))) : false;
```

And I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: await is not defined`.

Meanwhile, I have this code that works just fine:

```js
data.push(await new Promise(resolve => {
  const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      resolve(this.responseText);
    }
  };
  req.open("GET", `https://example.com/${id}/answer`, true);
  req.send();
}));
```

What am I missing?

Comment: A call to `await` *usually* has to be inside an `async` function.

Comment: To wit: running `async function foo(bar) { const baz = bar ? await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 10, 'hi')) : await Promise.resolve('bye!'); return baz; }` and calling it in my browser console seems to work just fine.

Comment: Looks as if the parser doesn't support `async`/`await`…

Comment: It works fine if `await` is expected, i.e. _directly_ in an `async` function, or top-level in a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you aren't in an async function, so `await` does not get interpreted as a keyword, but as a variable name. If you put the entire initial snippet into an async function, it'll work as expected.

What's going on with

> Unexpected token 'new'

and

> await is not defined

is that, when you're not in an async function, [those words are interpreted as normal identifiers (variable names)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55934490/why-are-await-and-async-valid-variable-names) - if you switch them out for another placeholder variable name, it makes more sense for why the syntax would be invalid:

```
foo = questionData.media ? (someVariable new Promise(resolve => {
```

```
foo = questionData.media ? (someVariable (new Promise(resolve => {
```

Neither of those makes sense, and so the parser will give you errors as expected, when you use `await` when not in an async function.

Comment: I just noticed that the larger snippet of code that this was taken out of contained an array map function which was not using an async function for its parameter.