# Is there an eslint rule to catch an await in non-async function?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Is there an eslint rule to catch an `await` used in a function that is not `async`. Perhaps I'm just not searching the correct keywords. Would love to have a rule such that the following code causes a linting error:

```js
function doSomething() {
  await doAsync()
}
```

EDIT: May be an issue with vim + ALE config? Any ideas there?

Thanks!

Comment: It'll cause a *syntax* error [in 99% of cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55934490/why-are-await-and-async-valid-variable-names), which (I'd think) would be sufficient. When a file has a syntax error and can't be parsed, ESLint can't lint it

Comment: I don't have any syntax errors thrown using vim + ale in these cases. What ruleset needs to be used for this to throw a syntax error in JS?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in ALE if it doesn't detect that that's invalid syntax

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. Will look into it

Comment: Its also not throwing a syntax error when running some tests, so I'll have to dig in

Comment: Your question "What ruleset needs to be used for this to throw a syntax error in JS" might get more answers on https://vi.stackexchange.com/