# Can't modify Mongoose data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have this code:

```
router.post('/BWreport', async function(req, res, next){
     try{
        var cname = await corporate.find().select('corporateID username');
        cname.forEach(function(cname, await){
          cname["totalcases"] = 1;
        });
        return res.json({ response:true, data:cname });
      }catch(err){
        return res.json({ response:false, data:err  });
      }
});
```

As you can see in the output, `totalcases` is not getting added:

```
    "response": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "61d3f90340b6cad5974ca50a",
            "username": "SB Demo",
            "corporateID": "SB00001"
        },
        {
            "_id": "62266f20fa0eb7a8fbe7d82a",
            "corporateID": "SB00002",
            "username": "NeoGrowth"
        }]
```

as you can see new key/value pair not getting in output, can anyone tell me why?
desired output below

```
    "response": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "61d3f90340b6cad5974ca50a",
            "username": "SB Demo",
            "corporateID": "SB00001",
            "totalcases": "1"
        },
        {
            "_id": "62266f20fa0eb7a8fbe7d82a",
            "corporateID": "SB00002",
            "username": "NeoGrowth",
            "totalcases": "1"
        }]
```

Comment: Which database are you using? Mongodb?

Comment: First problem is that you are using a keyword as a variable name, and reusing a variable name `function(cname, await)`

Comment: @vighnesh153 `await` is a reserved keyword so that also needs to be changed

Comment: Not entirely https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55934490/why-are-await-and-async-valid-variable-names (though in the circumstances that it appears it definitely deserves to be refactored out)

Comment: @CertainPerformance that is weird. As I was writing it, I thought to myself that it's weird that a new feature could introduce reserved words. Thanks for the correction. My statement was obviously wrong anyway since OP appeared to be using said code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose documents are immutable. Use `.lean()` to make it return a Javascript object that can be modified:

```
router.post('/BWreport', async function(req, res, next){
     try{
        var cname = await corporate.find().select('corporateID username').lean();

        cname.forEach(function(c, await){
          c["totalcases"] = 1;
        });

        return res.json({ response:true, data:cname });
        }catch(err){
        return res.json({ response:false, data:err  });
      }
});
```

Comment: lean() returns a JavaScript object instead of a Mongoose document. New key/value pair is not added because we can not modify mongoose document.

Comment: yep waiting for timer to end

Answer (score 1):

```
router.post('/BWreport', async function(req, res, next){
 try{
    var cname = await corporate.find().select('corporateID username');
    cname.forEach((elem, ind, arr) => {
      arr[ind]['totalcases'] = 1;
    });
    return res.json({ response:true, data:cname });
  }catch(err){
    return res.json({ response:false, data:err  });
  }
});
```

Comment: you can't still edit it unless you add `lean()` method.