# Why does this statement does not throw an error?

Tags: javascript, keyword

We all know that JavaScript reserved keywords cannot be used as variable names. For example, var, function, let, etc are considered special keywords in JavaScript. But consider this code:

```
var let = "Hi";
console.log(let); // prints out "Hi"
let var = "Hi";
console.log(var); // Syntax error
```

I am confused as to why the browser did not throw an error when I attempted to use it as variable name, but when I tried with var, it throws an error.

Comment: Best to just stay away from these keyword-overlapping names altogether. Even if it compiles, it's like having a co-pilot named "Roger".

Answer (score 1):

> `const` and `let` are recent additions to JS, but for a long time before they were added const was a reserved keyword (presumably on the basis that it was thought to be a likely future addition to the language).

> Since `let` used to be a valid variable name, this is presumably for backwards compatibility.

[var let is ok but let let isn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50789375/var-let-is-ok-but-let-let-isnt)